# TwitteR analysis on tweet trends

Tags: r, twitter

I am doing a twitter analysis on a few selected users on R. I used the twitteR package to get user data, and their tweets.

However there is a limitation of 3200 tweets on each user, but I would like to do an analysis on the number of tweets, retweets and replies by a particular user over time (probably since opening their user account). Is there any way of getting these numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API timeline for individual users is 3200 Tweets. The way to get more than that would be to use the full-archive search API, which is commercial. That does also provide a specific “count” endpoint that would enable you to discover how many times a specific user account Tweeted within a time period. I don’t think twitteR is developed any more, and rTweet is a more-commonly-used package now - I *believe* that it may have support for the premium full-archive search features, but you would want to check that.